# Sending data from HoloLens 2 to Arduino

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, hololens, mrtk

I am attempting to send data over bluetooth from my HoloLens 2 to an arduino device. From the documentation, I gathered that using RFCOMM will be the most straightforward and easiest method for me to do this (since there's literally an example code for RFCOMM given on the page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm)). Additionally, I'm choosing RFCOMM over the other supported method, GATT, because I have little experience developing for bluetooth.

I'm developing my app on Unity, using MRTK 2. The app works as expected for everything but the bluetooth connection part.

So far I have implemented the example code provided in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm), but unfortunately this causes the deployment to HoloLens process fail outright. Below is the error code I get when the build fails:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 32 seconds (31897 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 10 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I have attempted to debug this with my limited knowledge but have not been successful so far.

Below is the relevant code in my program:

```
...

#if WINDOWS_UWP
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;

Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService _service;
Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket _socket;
#endif

...

public class LightController : MonoBehaviour{
//this part is mainly for creating the connection as far as I can tell
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    bool firstSave = true;


// This App requires a connection that is encrypted but does not care about
// whether it's authenticated.
bool SupportsProtection(RfcommDeviceService service){
    switch (service.ProtectionLevel){
        case SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket:
            if ((service.MaxProtectionLevel == SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionWithAuthentication)
                || (service.MaxProtectionLevel == SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication)){
                // The connection can be upgraded when opening the socket so the
                // App may offer UI here to notify the user that Windows may
                // prompt for a PIN exchange.
                return true;
            }
            else{
                // The connection cannot be upgraded so an App may offer UI here
                // to explain why a connection won't be made.
                return false;
            }
        case SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionWithAuthentication:
            return true;
        case SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// This App relies on CRC32 checking available in version 2.0 of the service.
const uint SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 0x0300;
const byte SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 0x0A;   // UINT32
const uint MINIMUM_SERVICE_VERSION = 200;
async Task<bool> IsCompatibleVersionAsync(RfcommDeviceService service){
    var attributes = await service.GetSdpRawAttributesAsync(
        BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
    var attribute = attributes[SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID];
    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(attribute);

    // The first byte contains the attribute's type
    byte attributeType = reader.ReadByte();
    if (attributeType == SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE){
        // The remainder is the data
        uint version = reader.ReadUInt32();
        return version >= MINIMUM_SERVICE_VERSION;
    }
    else return false;
}

//this is called in the "Start()" function
async void Initialize(){
    // Enumerate devices with the object push service
    var services =
        await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
            RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));

    if (services.Count > 0){
        // Initialize target Bluetooth BR device
        var hc06Device = services.FirstOrDefault(service => service.Name == "HC-06");
        var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(hc06Device.Id);


        bool isCompatibleVersion = await IsCompatibleVersionAsync(service);

        // Check that the service meets this App's minimum requirement
        if (SupportsProtection(service) && isCompatibleVersion){
            _service = service;

            // Create a socket and connect to the target
            _socket = new StreamSocket();
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(
                _service.ConnectionHostName,
                _service.ConnectionServiceName,
                SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

            // The socket is connected. At this point the App can wait for
            // the user to take some action, for example, click a button to send a
            // file to the device, which could invoke the Picker and then
            // send the picked file. The transfer itself would use the
            // Sockets API and not the Rfcomm API, and so is omitted here for
            // brevity.
        }
    }
}

//this function is called every 14-seconds-ish, called within the "Update()" function.
async void DataSender(int LEDNumber) {
    string strOfLED = LEDNumber.ToString();
    var dataWriter = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);

    dataWriter.WriteString(strOfLED);
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    await dataWriter.FlushAsync();

    dataWriter.Close();
}
#endif

...

#if WINDOWS_UWP
    private void OnApplicationQuit() {
        _socket.Dispose();
    }
#endif
```